# How to add tab space to paragragh in itext java

Tags: java, itext

i am trying to add spaces between the string

Example:

```
Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
String para1="First Name :      chandra";
 preface.add(new Paragraph(para1, 
            new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 11,Font.NORMAL)));
document.add(preface);
```

i am expecting the output as:
First Name :        chandra
but i got the output as below:
First Name :chandra

Comment: If you're actually looking for a 'tab' then use "First Name :\tchandra";

Comment: PDFs aren't aware of the `\t` character, so that won't work @SHA1

Comment: @BrunoLowagie my bad. thanks for pointing that out. I should've checked what iText was before commenting